# How to get attributes of a foreign key

Tags: mysql

In a mySQL database, I have a table of users:

[image]

I also have a table of comments:

[image]

I need to get all of the comments where the posters and recipients are of different genders and display their ID's and Genders. I cannot figure out how to do this. My first step of trouble is I can't get the user's gender simply from their poster/recipient columns.

I tried
`comments.Poster.Gender` but that of course doesn't work. Poster and Recipient are foreign keys to users.ID

Comment: show your expected results?  also, text is much more friendly than images; a fiddle is best of all (e.g. put create table and insert statements in https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0, along with any sql you have attempted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join to users twice once for recipients and once for posters

```
SELECT c.*, p.Name AS poster_name, p.Gender AS poster_gender, r.Name AS recipient_name, r.Gender AS recipient_gender
  FROM comments c
  INNER JOIN users p ON (c.Poster    = p.ID)
  INNER JOIN users r ON (c.Recipient = r.ID)
  WHERE p.Gender <> r.Gender
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd join the `comments` table on the `users` table twice, once for the poster and once for the recipient, and then check their genders:

```sql
SELECT c.*, p.gender, r.gender
FROM   comments c
JOIN   users p ON c.poster = p.id
JOIN   users r ON c.recipient = r.id
WHERE  p.gender <> r.gender
```